# AWS Lambda - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda

So Ive looked at a fair few other posts pretty much having the same issue, but all of the solutions don't work for me and Im unsure where exactly Im going wrong...

This is the error:
https://gyazo.com/33c943b348e428367920f7922900f947

This is the class Im trying to access:
        public class AndrewTechSpeechletRequestStream extends SpeechletRequestStreamHandler {

```
private static final Set<String> supportedApplicationIds;
static {
    AndrewTechBot.run();
    /*
     * This Id can be found on https://developer.amazon.com/edw/home.html#/ "Edit" the relevant
     * Alexa Skill and put the relevant Application Ids in this Set.
     */
    supportedApplicationIds = new HashSet<>();
    supportedApplicationIds.add("uniquecode...");
    // supportedApplicationIds.add("[unique-value-here]");
}

public AndrewTechSpeechletRequestStream() {
    super(new AndrewTechSpeechlet(), supportedApplicationIds);
}

}
```

Im using Maven, so this is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.andrewtech.discord.skill</groupId>
<artifactId>AndrewTechBot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            main.java.com.andrewtech.discord.skill.AndrewTechSpeechletRequestStream
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            main.java.com.andrewtech.discord.skill.AndrewTechSpeechletRequestStream
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>.</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>${basedir}/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>bungeecord-repo</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mvnrepository.com</id>
        <url>mvnrepository.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-customsearch</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev55-1.22.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--<groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>invoicesdk</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>LATEST</version>-->
        <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-api-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
        <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
        <artifactId>ask-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To build the project, Im using clean, then package, then Im uploading it to my lambda function, clicking save then test, and well... thats the error that pops up. Can someone please help?